# Error al intentar recibir un objeto remoto mediante RMI

Tags: java, java-swing, rmi

Estoy intentando crear un programa que utiliza RMI, lo he revisado varias veces comprobando lo que tengo en los apuntes de clase pero no soy capaz de encontrar si he hecho algo mal.

Me sale el siguiente error en la clase VentanaRemota al recibir el objeto remoto:

```
Excepción : class jdk.proxy1.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to class Distribuida.InterfaceVentana (jdk.proxy1.$Proxy0 is in module jdk.proxy1 of loader 'app'; Distribuida.InterfaceVentana is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.proxy1.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to class Distribuida.InterfaceVentana (jdk.proxy1.$Proxy0 is in module jdk.proxy1 of loader 'app'; Distribuida.InterfaceVentana is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at Distribuida.VentanaRemota.<init>(VentanaRemota.java:21)
    at Distribuida.VentanaRemota$1.run(VentanaRemota.java:163)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Interfaz común(InterfaceVentana) tanto el cliente como el servidor estan en un mismo proyecto pero en paquetes distintos, la interfaz esta creada en ambos paquetes:

```
package Distribuida;

import Concurrencia.*;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

/**
 *
 * @author alema
 */
public interface InterfaceVentana extends Remote{
    
    String getCartasBuz() throws RemoteException;
    
    String getlistBuzon() throws RemoteException;
    
    String getf1() throws RemoteException;
    
    String getf2() throws RemoteException;
    
    String getfN1() throws RemoteException;
    
    String getfN2() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Objeto remoto(GestorVentanaRemota):

```
package Concurrencia;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author alema
 */
public class GestorVentanaRemota extends UnicastRemoteObject implements InterfaceVentana{
    private JTextField cartasBuz;
    private JTextField listBuzon;
    private JTextField f1;
    private JTextField f2;
    private JTextField fN1;
    private JTextField fN2;
    
   public GestorVentanaRemota(JTextField cartasBuz,JTextField listBuzon,JTextField f1,JTextField f2,JTextField fN1,JTextField fN2) throws RemoteException{
    this.cartasBuz=cartasBuz;
    this.listBuzon=listBuzon;
    this.f1=f1;
    this.f2=f2;
    this.fN1=fN1;
    this.fN2=fN2;         
} 
    
    public String getCartasBuz()throws RemoteException{
        return cartasBuz.getText();
    }
    public String getlistBuzon()throws RemoteException{
        return listBuzon.getText();
    }
    public String getf1()throws RemoteException{
        return f1.getText();
    }
    public String getf2()throws RemoteException{
        return f2.getText();
    }
    public String getfN1()throws RemoteException{
        return fN1.getText();
    }
    public String getfN2()throws RemoteException{
        return fN2.getText();
    }
}
```

Codigo Servidor(Ventana) para el objeto remoto, solo creo el objeto de tipo GestorVentana Remota creo el registry en el puerto 1099 y los hago visible con naming.rebind en localhost:

```
package Concurrencia;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

/**
 *
 * @author alemar
 */
public class Ventana extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        private GestorEjecucion geGlobal = new GestorEjecucion();
        private GestorEjecucion ge1 = new GestorEjecucion();
        private GestorEjecucion ge2 = new GestorEjecucion();
        private GestorEjecucion ge3 = new GestorEjecucion();
        private GestorEjecucion ge4 = new GestorEjecucion();
        private GestorEjecucion ge5 = new GestorEjecucion();
    public Ventana() {
        initComponents();
        try{
            GestorVentanaRemota obj = new GestorVentanaRemota(cartasBuz,listBuzon,f1,f2,fN1,fN2);
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            Naming.rebind("//localhost/GestorVentanaRemota", obj); 
        }catch(Exception ex){}
        
        Buzon buz = new Buzon(cartasBuz,listBuzon);
        Furgoneta fur1 = new Furgoneta(f1,fN1);
        Furgoneta fur2 = new Furgoneta(f2,fN2);
        
        
        Empleado emp1 = new Empleado("Empleado1",buz,fur1,fur2,e1,geGlobal,ge1);
        Empleado emp2 = new Empleado("Empleado2",buz,fur1,fur2,e2,geGlobal,ge2);
        Empleado emp3 = new Empleado("Empleado3",buz,fur1,fur2,e3,geGlobal,ge3);
        Empleado emp4 = new Empleado("Empleado4",buz,fur1,fur2,e4,geGlobal,ge4);
        Empleado emp5 = new Empleado("Empleado5",buz,fur1,fur2,e5,geGlobal,ge5);
        emp1.start();
        emp2.start();
        emp3.start();
        emp4.start();
        emp5.start();
        for (int i=1;i<=400;i++){
            Persona per = new Persona("Persona"+i,buz,geGlobal);
            per.start();
            }
        
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {}

        /* Create and display the form */

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Ventana().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton bAll;
    private javax.swing.JButton bE1;
    private javax.swing.JButton bE2;
    private javax.swing.JButton bE3;
    private javax.swing.JButton bE4;
    private javax.swing.JButton bE5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField cartasBuz;
    private javax.swing.JTextField e1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField e2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField e3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField e4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField e5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField f1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField f2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fN1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fN2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JTextField listBuzon;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Código Cliente(VentanaRemota) recibo el objeto remoto con "naming.lookup" y fuerzo que sea del tipo "InterfaceVentana", creo que el error se produce al intentar que sea de tipo "InterfaceVentana" pero no entiendo bien que pasa ya que con otros programas lo ha hecho así y no me ha dado ningún problema:

```
package Distribuida;
import java.rmi.Naming;

/**
 *
 * @author alema
 */
public class VentanaRemota extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public VentanaRemota() {
        initComponents();
        try{
            InterfaceVentana obj = (InterfaceVentana) Naming.lookup("//127.0.0.1/GestorVentanaRemota");
            ActualizadorVentana av = new ActualizadorVentana(obj,cartasBuz,listBuzon,f1,f2,fN1,fN2);
            System.out.println("a");
            av.start();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Excepción : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
    
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {}

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField cartasBuz;
    private javax.swing.JTextField f1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField f2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fN1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fN2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JTextField listBuzon;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido encontrar el problema, se produce porque como lo tenia separado en dos paquetes cree dos veces la misma interfaz una en cada paquete, pero lo que hay que hacer es crear una sola interfaz a la que puedan acceder ambos.

Para ello simplemente lo deje en el paquete Concurrencia, y para las clases del otro paquete que necesitaban acceder a la interfaz añadi:

```
import Compartido.InterfaceVentana;
```